# Telerik Reporting How to force the 'Contract' selection whether user selects it or not

Tags: telerik-reporting, multivalue, reportparameter

I want to force the parameter "Contract" to be returned whether the user selects it from the drop-down list or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `NeedDataSource` event for that. Take a look at the documentation for it here: https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-parameters-programmatic-control

Specifically pay attention to this code sample:

```
private void Report1_NeedDataSource(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Take the Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report instance
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report report = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report)sender;

    // Transfer the value of the processing instance of ReportParameter
    // to the parameter value of the sqlDataSource component
    // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN FIND YOUR PARAMETER AND MODIFY ITS VALUE
    this.sqlDataSource1.Parameters[0].Value = report.Parameters["ManagerID"].Value;

    // Set the SqlDataSource component as it's DataSource
    report.DataSource = this.sqlDataSource1;
}
```

Since your parameter is multi-value you will need to create an `IEnumerable`. Then you can add the values of the parameter that the user selected to the `IEnumerable`. Then check to see if the user selected `"Contract"`, and if not then add it to the list. Finally add the `IEnumerable` to the data source's parameter's value property.